# Does code motion/hoisting happen on if statements/branches?

Tags: loop-invariants

Consider the following C code:

```
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    if (operation == 0) {
        a[i] *= 2;
    } else {
        a[i] += 1;
    }
}
```

Would a real compiler (GCC) be able to do this optimization? If so, what is it called/how is it found?

```
if (operation == 0) {    
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {        
        a[i] *= 2;        
    }
} else {
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {        
        a[i] += 1;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try and see? You can look at the assembly code produced by the compiler.

Comment: Looks like it does with -O3 but not by default

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. Questions about the principles behind compilers are absolutely on-topic, here, but "Does this actual compiler do this thing?" isn't a question about computer _science_.